# Passing a generic function in as a callback in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to preserve the type information of arguments to a callback, where the callback is a generic:

```
function Foo<Template>(argument: Template) {
  // Do something with argument
}

function Bar(callback: Function) {
  callback('something')
}

let x = Bar( Foo<String> )
```

This does not look like valid typescript syntax. Any way to do this?

Comment: You can just do `let x = Bar(Foo)`, but I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.  The function `Foo` takes a generic type parameter but it doesn't have to, since it's not doing anything special with it.  And `Bar` doesn't seem to care what kind of function it takes.  Maybe you could flesh out the example with some more motivating use cases?

Comment: @jcalz can we also not pass specific type as a parameter?
In below example, when we pass doSomothing as a param, can we also pass the type along with it?
thisFirst(doSomething<string>)

Answer (score 14):

Expanding on the answer of Rodrigo here. If you have a function with a generic:

```
function doSomething<T>(t: T): void {
    console.log("oh " + t);
}
```

You can define the type of the function as follows:

```
type Handler = <T>(t: T) => void;
```

Then you can use the type `Handler` as a function parameter:

```
function thisFirst(callback: Handler) {
  callback<string>('boink');
}

thisFirst(doSomething)
```

Comment: can we also not pass specific type as a parameter?
In above example, when we pass doSomothing as a param, can we also pass the type along with it?
thisFirst(doSomething<string>)

Answer (score 5):

You can define a generic function for callback with a generic argument like this:

```
const handleSomething =
  <T extends (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>>(callback: T) =>
  (...args: Parameters<T>) =>
    callback(...args)
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved my time for passing dynamic arguments.

Comment: I'm getting such an error on the generic: `TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.`

Answer (score 2):

`Function` is any function. Try to specify the callback.

```
function Foo<Template>(argument: Template) {
  // Do something with argument
}

function Bar(callback: { (argument: string) }) {
  callback('something')
}

let x = Bar(Foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are useful if the function with the callback parameters is defined in your code.
Here is the more generic solution that will always work:

```
    
    
function Foo<Template>(argument: Template) {
  // Do something with argument
}

function Bar(callback: Function) {
  callback('something')
}

let x = Bar( (argument: String) => Foo<String>(argument) ) // using arrow functions
let x1 = Bar(function(argument: String) {
   return Foo<String>(argument)
}
```

In the above code, we create a new anonymous function that has the same arguments as the callback function, calls the function Foo specifying the type and returns whatever Foo will return.